# Throw inside of mocha test not being picked up

Tags: typescript, chai

I don't understand why my test is failing, despite all of the logger messages printing:

```
it('should reject subscription to a invalid path', async () => {
    const client = fayeConfig.client;
    let subscription: any;

    expect(() => {
        subscription = client.subscribe('/bad_path', (msg: Object) => {
            // do nothing
        });

        subscription.then(() => {
            // 'This should never happen.
            subscription.cancel();
        }, (error: Object) => {
            subscription.cancel();
            logger.debug(`my error ${error}`);
            throw new Error(error.toString());
        }).catch((err: Error) => {
            subscription.cancel();
            logger.debug('something is fishy '+err);
            throw err;
        });
    }).to.throw();
});
```

I expect the error to bubble up. Any help is appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: I suspect that this is due to TypeScripts lack of support for multi-try-catch https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8677

Comment: @JanacMeena Thanks for that link, but the solution was a little more basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `expect` is expecting a synchronous function, and I am providing a `Promise`. So it calls the function and then moves on. To solve this issue, I had to wrap the function call in a separate function and then wait for it to resolve.

```js
it('should reject subscription to a invalid path', async () => {
    const client = fayeConfig.client;
    let subscription: any;

    const testPromise = async () => {
        subscription = client.subscribe('/bad_path', (msg: Object) => {
            // do nothing
        });

        return subscription.then(() => {
            subscription.cancel();
        }, (error: any) => {
            subscription.cancel();
            throw new Error(`This is the correct behaviour : ${error}`);
        });
    };

    let test: any = null;

    try {
        await testPromise();
    } catch (error) {
        test = error;
    }

    expect(test).to.be.not.null;
});
```